# How to convert a CSV from DMS to WGS84 in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, convert, wgs84, degrees-minutes-seconds

I would like to automatically convert from a Degree - minute - second system to WGS84 EPSG:32632. I have a CSV with these kind of values:

```
LATITUDINE  LONGITUDINE
46°01’24,7” 11°13’47,5”
45°42’07,5” 10°55’11,3”
46°01’37,6” 11°06’41,7”
46°15’03,7” 11°11’00,1”
```

and I would like to automatically convert them. 
There is a way? They are a lot, if not I would do with a normal converter...
I try to import them in QGIS (but only a few of them works) and export them in some way, but I sincerely do not understand how to. Any suggestion?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If you are running QGIS 2.0.1, you can import the data as delimited text layer.

It offers you to select DMS Coordinates, comma as decimal separator and EPSG:4326 as CRS.

Once you have the data loaded, you can rightclick on the layer -> Save as and choose EPSG:32632 for the output file.